# jQuery UI Slider - Disable click on slider track

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to disable the click on my jQuery UI Slider's track.  Clicking on the handle is ok but I do not want the handle to respond if the user clicks on the track.

slider set up in document.ready() as follows:

```
$('#navScroller').slider({
      value: 0,
      start: onNavScrollStart,
      slide: onNavScrollSlide,
      animate: slideSpeed,
      max: slideWidth
});
```

I tried both:

```
$('#navScroller').unbind('click');
```

and

```
$('#navScroller .ui-slider').unbind('click');
```

neither of which worked to stop the slider from responding to track clicks.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Thanks!

EDIT:
I just discovered that using:

```
$('#navScroller').unbind('mousedown');
```

removes clicks from the whole slider, handle and all, which is closer to what i need but I still need to be able to drag the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should take care of it.

```
/**
 *  Turns off the track click for the given slider control
 */

function disableSliderTrack($slider){

    $slider.bind("mousedown", function(event){

        return isTouchInSliderHandle($(this), event);   

    });

    $slider.bind("touchstart", function(event){

        return isTouchInSliderHandle($(this), event.originalEvent.touches[0]);

    });
}

function isTouchInSliderHandle($slider, coords){

    var x = coords.pageX;
    var y = coords.pageY;

    var $handle = $slider.find(".ui-slider-handle");

    var left = $handle.offset().left;
    var right = (left + $handle.outerWidth());
    var top = $handle.offset().top;
    var bottom = (top + $handle.outerHeight());

    return (x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom);    
}


    disableSliderTrack($(".ui-slider"));
```

Answer (score 16):

There's a non-JS solution to this as well, using only two lines of CSS:

```css
/* Supress pointer events */
#navSlider { pointer-events: none; }
/* Enable pointer events for slider handle only */
#navSlider .ui-slider-handle { pointer-events: auto; }
```

Comment: Perfect solution. A minor correction `#navSlider .ui-slider-handle { point-events: auto; }` should be `#navSlider .ui-slider-handle { pointer-events: auto; }`. pointer-events instead of point-events

Comment: @jaron Thanks this works for me, just to point out for everybody, if your class doesn't match the example (because mine didn't) look for your parent div class or id and change it to that. eg my parent div was .ui-slider-horizontal. but thanks this worked great with a minimal, clean approach, I can't believe i didn't remember this.

Comment: amazing solution, thanks

Answer (score 7):

@btate has the right idea (abandoning mousedown/touchstart that don't originate in the slider handle), but there is an easier way to get there. jQuery's event object will tell you which element initiated the event.

```
var sliderMouseDown = function (e) { // disable clicks on track
    var sliderHandle = $('#navScroller').find('.ui-slider-handle');
    if (e.target != sliderHandle[0]) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
};

$('#navScroller')
    .on('mousedown', sliderMouseDown)
    .on('touchstart', sliderMouseDown)
    .slider({
          value: 0,
          start: onNavScrollStart,
          slide: onNavScrollSlide,
          animate: slideSpeed,
          max: slideWidth
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

As JQuery already bound your container (slider) div with mouse down event, so even if you unbind your range div from it, it'll still fire on the container div,

here's the solution:

```
$('#navScroller .ui-slider-range').mousedown(function() {
      return false;
});
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I will give this a shot this week as soon as I get some time, and I will mark your answer if it works!

Answer (score 4):

```
    $("#slider").slider({ disabled: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yangmillstheory/JQ9m8/)

```
var sliding = false;

var slide = function (ev, ui) {

    if (ev.originalEvent.type !== 'mousemove') {
        sliding = false;
        return false;
    }

    sliding = true;

    console.log("I'm sliding.");

};

var start = function (ev, ui) {

    if (!sliding) {
       console.log("I'm not sliding.");
    }

};

var stop = function (ev, ui) {

    sliding ? console.log('I slid.') : console.log('I clicked.');

    sliding = false;

};

$('#slider').slider({
    slide: slide,
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
});
```

Comment: Very helpful that you used `ev.originalEvent.type`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and i could not find any solution unless i decided to remove the handle from jquery ui itself

In ui.slider.js, Comment this lines.
// Bind the click to the slider itself

```
this.element.bind('mousedown.slider', function(e) {
   self.click.apply(self, [e]);
   self.currentHandle.data("mouse").trigger(e);
   self.firstValue = self.firstValue + 1; //This is for always triggering the change event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Heh, more than 2 years, but, here is my solution:

```
$('a.ui-slider-handle').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#slider").slider({ disabled: true });
```

Comment: to me, it still allows to drag the slider

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already old and answered, but a non-javascript solution I came up with was to put the slider in a wrapper, style the wrapper to look how I wanted the track to look and set the height of the slider to 0.

Some margin tweaking is required to have everything line up but it was fairly easy and worked perfectly for me.

```
<div class="slide-wrap">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

.slide-wrap {
    width: 300px;
    height: 15px;
    border: solid 1px #666;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border: none;
    overflow: visible;
}

.slider .ui-slider-handle {
     margin: 2px 0 0;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83Hwf/1/

Answer (score 0):

This one did the trick for me (just make sure to detach the document event lister when destroying the slider object)

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

              <style>
                .slider.ui-slider-disabled {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
              </style>

              <script>

              $(function() {

                $(".slider").slider({
                    range: true,

                    create: function( event, ui ) {

                       var disabled = true;
                       $(".slider").slider( "disable" );

                       $('.ui-slider-handle').on('mousedown',    function(event) {
                          disabled = false;
                          $(".slider").slider( "enable" );
                       });  

                        $(document).on('mouseup', function(event) {
                          if (!disabled) {
                             $(".slider").slider("disable");
                             disabled = true;
                          }
                       });  
                    }
                });

              });

              </script>



            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="slider"></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having spent a while looking for a solution or something that would help get me closer to what I was after, I came up with the following, which appears to work in all browsers:

```
    var _sliderEvents = [];     

    $('.slider').each(function (i) {
        var _slider = $(this);
        _sliderEvents.push($._data(_slider[0]).events.mousedown);
        $._data(_slider[0]).events.mousedown = {};
        _slider.on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $._data(_slider[0]).events.mousedown = _sliderEvents[i];
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $._data(_slider[0]).events.mousedown = {};
            }
        }, '.ui-slider-handle');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/digits/fxef8398/ You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add **behaviour: none**

```
noUiSlider.create(monday_shift_time_slider, {
    behaviour: "none"
});
```