# jQuery UI Slider - disable sliding on track/enable on handle mousedown

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, handle

I have a jQuery UI Slider, which I want to disable when a user tries to slide using the track. It should only work/enable when someone drags the handle somewhere. Clicking and trying to drag the sliding to move the handle should be disabled. I'm not sure if this can be done using `unbind` or `mousedown` event.

The problem I notice is, my handle goes from 1 to 100. When you move the start of the handle, it displays uses the `ui.value`. But if you try to go outside the handle and slide on the slider track, the `ui.value` resets its value.

So, I want to disable non-handle dragging.

Comment: can you show us the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can understand as I'm little confused with your question.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done useing 2 line css code!

This is HTML

```
<div class="SliderContainer"><div id="BGS0"></div></div>
```

This is JS

```
$('#BGS0').slider();
```

This is CSS

```
.SliderContainer {
   pointer-events: none;
   /* Other settings here */
}

.SliderContainer > .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
pointer-events: auto;
/* Other settings here */
}
```

**NOTE:** I used SliderContainer Class as a parent DIV, because any pointer event is disabled inside this DIV by default. Then I enabled pointer event for slider handle only. Only sliders inside parent DIV are affected by this option, because I used `.SliderContainer > .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle` selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#range-amount").slider({ disabled: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and i could not find any solution unless i decided to remove the handle from jquery ui itself

In `ui.slider.js`, Comment this lines.

```
// Bind the click to the slider itself
this.element.bind('mousedown.slider', function(e) {
   self.click.apply(self, [e]);
   self.currentHandle.data("mouse").trigger(e);
   self.firstValue = self.firstValue + 1; //This is for always triggering the change event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using this solution:

[jQuery UI Slider - Disable click on slider track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330854/jquery-ui-slider-disable-click-on-slider-track/13201163#13201163)

```
function disableSliderTrack($slider){

    $slider.bind("mousedown", function(event){

        return isTouchInSliderHandle($(this), event);   

    });

    $slider.bind("touchstart", function(event){

        return isTouchInSliderHandle($(this), event.originalEvent.touches[0]);

    });
}

function isTouchInSliderHandle($slider, coords){

    var x = coords.pageX;
    var y = coords.pageY;

    var $handle = $slider.find(".ui-slider-handle");

    var left = $handle.offset().left;
    var right = (left + $handle.outerWidth());
    var top = $handle.offset().top;
    var bottom = (top + $handle.outerHeight());

    return (x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom);    
}


disableSliderTrack($(".ui-slider"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm clear on your question, you don't want the slider to slide on mouse events, this should work:

```
$( "#slider" ).mousedown(function(){return false;}); // For mousedown
$( "#slider" ).scroll(function(){return false;}); // For scrolling with the trackpad
```

Also checkout the jquery events list and just substitute any event to remove this event from the slider, like:

```
$( "#slider" ).someEvent(function(){return false;});
```

To remove all events from the slider, try:

```
$('#slider').unbind();
```

Comment: Thanks...that's kind of what I'm trying to do. But the slider should only move/enable when using the slider handle. Anything outside the handle should be disabled.

Comment: Great, well all you have to do is remove all events from the slider, and only work with events on the slider handle :), i have updated the answer to show this