# jQuery mobile slider handle - stop dragging but allow track selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile slider and would like to stop the slider handle from dragging however I would still like it to move along the slider track when the user selects a point on the track.  I have tried the following:

```
     $('.ui-slider').live(' mousemove touchmove', function(){
         return false;
     });
```

Comment: in theory, you need to disable touchmove on the handle and enable click/touch on the track

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is here: [jQuery UI Slider - disable sliding on track/enable on handle mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093156/jquery-ui-slider-disable-sliding-on-track-enable-on-handle-mousedown)

I'm gonna try it with `$('.ui-slider-handle').mousedown(function(){return false;});` and let you know