# Disabling click or mousedown event on jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to disable the click or mousedown event on the Slider tract. I want the slider to only move by dragging the handle. I tried adding preventDefault() and return false to the slider but no use. Its still triggering the jump.

Example: 
http://jsbin.com/iguruh/1/edit

I know this is similar to this [jQuery UI Slider - Disable click on slider track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330854/jquery-ui-slider-disable-click-on-slider-track) 
but the solutions provided there are not working because i have the range option set to false.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

did you tryed this?:

```
$(element).bind('click',function(){
return false;

});
```

Comment: I just tried it in the above jsbin url. Not working. I am pretty sure jQuery-UI is listening to a mousedown event rather than a click because return false for a mousedown event on the .ui-slider-range element worked. However, i don't have a range option in my code and adding it will only solve half the problem. The .ui-slider-range sits on the left side of the slider, so only clicks on the left side gets cancelled.